# How do I extract test line by line from a text file in terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, wget, text, extract

So I have a .sh script that needs to wget a lot of files. I have a text file set up like this

```
http://www.website.com/w4w4wbvert9rtr/video.mp4
http://www.website.com/wserteg444gs4r/video.mp4
http://www.website.com/9we75y49wc45gr/video.mp4
http://www.website.com/sfwetb456/video.mp4
```

So I am wondering if there is a way that I can extract the text line by line and insert in into wget so I would just have to run wget and then a variable.

edit:

I used [G Trawo](https://askubuntu.com/users/476285/g-trawo)'s answer but made a small adjustment. I set it up to download all of the files at the same time by using `gnome-terminal -e "wget $line"` instead of just wget $line

Thanks,

Zimbinskers

Comment: It's straightforward using the bash shell's builtin `read` command: however, `wget` already has an option (`-i file` or `--input-file=file`) to read a list of URLs from a file, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment above already mentions that `wget` has the `--input-file=file` switch. If you want to do it with a script, follow below. Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/bash-scripting-read-file-line-by-line).

Fill a file named `listofurls.txt` with all your URLs.

Create a file called `wget_readfile.sh`

```
nano wget_readfile.sh
```

Paste this into it:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
wget $line
done < "$1"
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x wget_readfile.sh
```

Run it

```
./wget_readfile.sh listofurls.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped out a lot but just so you know their is an extra **'** at the end of your code, I removed the extra apostrophe and it worked!